# NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/

Tags: django

I am following Django 2.0 tutorial Part4 and encounter the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/
Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls\\/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)\\/vote\\/$']
```

The urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

The views.py, I followed the official tutorial strictly step by step:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Question, Choice


def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, "polls/detail.html", {'question':question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        #Redisplay the question voting form
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question':question,
            'error_message':"You did'nt select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

**template**

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}
    <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
{% endif %}

<form  action="{% url 'polls:vote' question_id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in queston.choice_set.all  %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice_id }}"/>
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label> <br>

    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit"  value="Vote"/>
</form>
```

I cannot locate the bug.

Comment: The problem is in your template, which you haven't shown.

Comment: ty, I am rechecking the codes and attached the template code in answer. @DanielRoseman

Comment: Why did you put it as an answer? It's not one. Edit your question and put it there.

Comment: why didn't you just update your question rather than post an answer?

Comment: It remind me "too many codes" , I edited it now.@Lemayzeur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your action url is not correct
instead of question_id, put question.id

```
<form  action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
```